Galois cover made by intermediate fields
(This is my high school math research, which is about applying ideas of algebraic geometry to galois theory. I know that my theory has no big meaning to real math. I am trying to make new definitions.)
Let $K/F$ be finite galois extension, and let $L$ and $C_i(i\in I)$ be intermediate fields. If $L$ is the smallest intermediate field that contains $C_i(i\in I)$, we will call $C_i(i\in I)$ pregalois cover of $L$. Pregalois cover that has itself as only sub-pregalois cover will be called galois cover. Is it true that galois cover statisfy restriction property? That is, if $L/H/F$, and $C_i(i\in I)$ is galois cover of $L$, then is $H\cap C_i(i\in I)$ galois cover of $H$?
I am tring to check if I can apply grothendieck topology into my research, by checking properties of galois cover.

Could you share with us your attempt so far, what your thoughts on the problem are ?
